# Using NOT (!) operator in R with numbers

Tags: r, operators

I'm trying to understand the ! operator better in R, and I'm confused as to how it applies to numbers. What does the following code signify, and why are the two equality queries not the same?

```
> !5 == 7
[1] TRUE
> 5 == !7
[1] FALSE
> !5
[1] FALSE
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check `?Syntax` for operator precedence and play around with parentheses.

Comment: General note: don't write `!5 == 7` even if you know the order of operations. You'll just confuse yourself or someone else down the road. `5 != 7` is also a thing, btw.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: the `!` operator coerces non-logicals to logical, then reverses them. Anything other than 0 evaluates to a logical `TRUE`, then the `!` operator flips it to `FALSE`

The rest has to do with order of operations.

```
!5 == 7
```

Evaluates to

```
!(5==7)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
!(FALSE)
```

Which returns `TRUE`

Whereas

```
5 == !7
```

Evaluates to

```
5 == FALSE
```

Which returns `FALSE`

The equivalent to `5 == !7` would be `(!5) == 7` (Both return `FALSE`)

Comment: Ah, order of operations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `!` coerces its argument to a logical, thus:

```
as.logical(-3L:3L)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
as.logical(seq(-2,2, by = 0.5))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

As you can see, 0 is FALSE, everything else is TRUE.

To get an even better sense of this, see that `!` is - like everything in R - a function:

```
> `!`
function (x)  .Primitive("!")
```

So, you're applying the `!` function to numeric arguments, which are coerced to logical, as above.

When you compare a logical to a numeric value using `==`, the numeric value is also coerced to logical.

In your first example (`!5 == 7`) is due to precedence ordering; `==` is higher precedence than `!`.